# Place an image at the top of a DIV and center it

Tags: html, css

I have 2 containers, one grey, one white. I'd like to place an image (this will be a triangle down) to the very top of the white background and center it horizontally. How could I achieve this? I have tried the following but that doesn't work

See https://jsfiddle.net/63s86hf9/

[image]

HTML

```
<section id="services" class="padding-onlytop-lg">
     <div class="container"><img src="http://placehold.it/92x45" class="triangle" alt="triangle-greg" width="92" height="45">
         <div class="row col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 inner-content padding-onlybottom-lg">
```

CSS:

```
.triangle {
margin-left: 0;
margin-right: 0;
margin: auto;
margin-top: -80px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this code..

```
.triangle {
    display: block;
    margin: -80px auto 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your .triangle class to this. You need to make it display as block. And add bottom margin to add space between title and the image.

```
.triangle {
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: -76px;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
#id{
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

or

```
#id {
    text-align: center;
   margin-top:0px;
}
```

change value of margin-top according to your requirement

Answer (score 0):

`margin:auto` only works on block elements.

```
.triangle {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: -80px;
  display: block;
}
```

(Your declarations for margin-left and -right are superfluous, since you are overwriting them with `margin: auto` on the next line anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

```css
    .container{
position:relative;
}
.triangle {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    top: -130px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `position: relative` into `.padding-onlytop-lg`. Example

```
.padding-onlytop-lg {
    padding-top: 75px !important;
    position: relative;
}
```

And Write in the flowing way

```
.triangle {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 0;
}
```